# How to load local html pages to android

Tags: android

I want to load local HTML pages in to a WebView. I know how to do it in iPhone. Can any one tell me the way to do it in android.

How to do the below page in android?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a TextView textArea and set it's text with the html string
You can define the string as a part of strings.xml file with your html tags and make sure you call getText(T.string.your_html_string) to fetch the html based text

```
    <string name="your_html_text">"Press <font fgcolor="#ffffffff"><b>Menu</b></font> and touch:\n
    \n<li><font fgcolor="#ffffffff"><b>Create </b></font> to create\n</li>
    \n<li><font fgcolor="#ffffffff"><b>Delete All</b></font> to delete all\n</li>
    </string>
```

and setText like

textArea.setText(getText(R.string.your_html_text));

Answer (score 2):

put your file to asset folder than you can use the code below

```
  WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.yourwebview);
  webview .loadUrl("file:///android_asset/UI/mylocalhtmlfile.htm");
```

Answer (score 2):

use this.

```
yourWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/yourfileName.html");
```

Comment: note: "file:///android_asset" is located at "<Project folder name>/assets"